# find least common denominator for list of fractions in python

Tags: python, math, fractions

I have a list of fractions

```
from fractions import Fraction

fractions_list=[Fraction(3,14),Fraction(1,7),Fraction(9,14)]
```

The output should be a list with the numerators for each fraction, then the denominator for all of them at the end and in simplest form. For above example the result (3/14, 2/14, 9/14) would be represented as follows

```
[3,2,9,14]
```

Is there an elegant solution for this? All I can think of involves a lot of intermediate lists to store some variables and scales horribly.

Comment: Er... how exactly are you getting from `3/14`, `1/7` and `9/14` to `7/21`, `6/21` and `8/21`?

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is correct? I think that it should be 3, 14 instead of 3/14 unless you write these on a string.

Comment: `numpy.lcm` would work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

fractions_list=[Fraction(3,14),Fraction(1,7),Fraction(9,14)]

lcm = np.lcm.reduce([fr.denominator for fr in fractions_list])

vals = [int(fr.numerator * lcm / fr.denominator) for fr in fractions_list]
vals.append(lcm)
```