# Is it possible to find a few common multiples of a list of numbers, without them having to be integers?

Tags: math, arithmetic-expressions, greatest-common-divisor

I don't even know if something like this is possible, but:

Let us say we have three numbers:

```
A = 6
B = 7.5
C = 24
```

I would like to find a few evenly spaced common multiples of these numbers between 0 and 2.
So the requirement is: one_of_these_numbers / common_multiple = an_integer (or almost an integer with a particular tolerance)

For example, a good result would be `[0.1 , 0.5 , 1 , 1.5]`

I have no idea if this is possible, because one can not iterate through a range of floats, but is there a smart way to do it?

I am using python, but a solution could be represented in any language of your preference.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: According to your definition, each value 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc will be a common "multiple". So, what is a "good multiple"?

Comment: A good result has evenly spaced numbers between 0 and 2.

Comment: If your domain is all real numbers, then for every number `X` and integer `0<A<X` there is another real number `Y` such that `X/Y=A`, where A is an integer. Proof: `Y=X/A ==> X/(X/A)=A ==> A=A` QED.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question or explain in a bit more detail? I don't understand at all what you're trying to do. In your example, how do you arrive at [0.1 , 0.5 , 1 , 1.5]?

Comment: If you divide A, B, and C by the numbers in this list [0.1 , 0.5 , 1 , 1.5], you will get an integer. I am trying to code a solution to be able to find such a list in python. Optimally, the numbers in the list should be well spaced. I came up with a solution that is working pretty well till now, you can check it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing my question, I actually came up with an idea for the solution.

To find common divisors using code, we have to work with integers.

My solution is to multiply all numbers by a factor = 1, 10, 100, ...
so that we can act as if they are integers, find their integer common divisors, and then redivide them by the factor to get a result.

Better explained in code:

```
a = 6
b = 7.5
c = 24

# Find a few possible divisors between 0 and 2 so that all numbers are divisible 
by div.

# We define a function that finds all divisors in a range of numbers, supposing 
all numbers are integers.

def find_common_divisors(numbers, range_start, range_end):
    results = []
    for i in range(range_start + 1, range_end + 1):
        if all([e % i == 0 for e in numbers]):
            results.append(i)
    return results

def main():
    nums = [a, b, c]
    range_start = 0
    range_end = 2
    factor = 1
    results = [1]
    while factor < 11:
        nums_i = [e * factor for e in nums]
        range_end_i = range_end * factor

        results += [e / factor for e in find_common_divisors(nums_i, range_start, range_end_i)]

        factor *= 10

    print(sorted(set(results)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For these particular numbers, I get the output:

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 1.5]
```

If we need more results, we can adjust `while factor < 11:` to a higher number than 11 like 101.

I am curious to see if I made any mistake in my code.
Happy to hear some feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: To get the integers by multiplying by a common denominator, I suggest using module fractions: [find least common denominator for list of fractions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054415/find-least-common-denominator-for-list-of-fractions-in-python)